# SAME code with changes in WHERE clause inside a sub query gives different result SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the difference between 2 code snippets that are similar since it is giving different results.

In the code below, The count is 15506

```
select 
 application_ID,
 userid,
 product,
 sub_product,
 ts_est,
 event_type from
(
   Select
  fa.ApplicationId as application_ID,
  ro.userid,
  ro.product,
  ro.sub_product,
  ro.ts_est,
  ro.event_type,
  from_utc_timestamp(fa.bornondate, 'America/New_York') as app_bornondate,
  row_number() over(
    partition by ro.userid, ro.product, ro.event_type
    order by
      fa.bornondate desc
  ) as rowid
from
  T1 ro
  left join T2 fa on ro.userid = fa.userid
  where event_type = "OS"
  and cast(ts_est as date)  >= '2021-10-05' and cast(ts_est as date) <= '2022-03-07' and product = "pt" 
)
where rowid = 1
```

Here is the 2nd code snippet where I have used the conditions outside the subquery. The count is 15096

```
select
 application_ID,
 userid,
 product,
 sub_product,
 ts_est,
 event_type from
 (
Select
  fa.ApplicationId as application_ID,
  ro.userid,
  ro.product,
  ro.sub_product,
  ro.ts_est,
  ro.event_type,
  from_utc_timestamp(fa.bornondate, 'America/New_York') as app_bornondate,
  row_number() over(
    partition by ro.userid, ro.product, ro.event_type
    order by
      fa.bornondate desc
  ) as rowid
from
  T1 ro
  left join T2 fa on ro.userid = fa.userid
  )
where rowid = 1 and cast(ts_est as date)  >= '2021-10-05' 
and cast(ts_est as date) <= '2022-03-07' and product = "pt" and event_type = "OS"
```

When I am using a minus operation for the two codes. It is showing 410 differences but the userid is present in both the tables which is strange.

I am new to sql and I'm having trouble taking this further though.

Thanks!

Comment: I have removed the tag spam here; please only tag the product(s) you are *really* using. SQL Server and MySQL, for example, are *completely* different RDBMS.

Comment: Standard TSQL has no function from_utc_timestamp and does not use double quotes as string delimiters. So probably not SQL Server.

Comment: I am using Spark SQL here. These functions are running fine.